# What does "utility purpose" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "utility purpose" mean in the text "Cycling is being encouraged for utility purposes (such as journeys to work, school and the shops)"?

Comment: Who knows? Where did you see that? They probably meant for practical purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utility means useful, practical, or helpful. You can have a utilitarian attitude, clothes, or outlook on life meaning you choose the objects or things in life for a practical or helpful reason rather than an aesthetic one.

Such as: 
"I buy iPhones because I think they're cool, unlike my utilitarian friend who still uses his Nokia 3310."

Applying that to your text, journeys to work, school and the shops may be rather short in comparison to other journeys you may make - so it would be practical or helpful (for your health, environment, etc...) to use a bicycle rather than to drive.

Comment: I agree. I this context, utility purposes would be in contrast to recreational or competitive purposes.